# Loop over Observable

Tags: html, angular

In my frontend part of application use a method

```
this.knowledgeMan.getUserAllowedCases(Item.ItemNumber)
```

which returns Observable. On my backend part, this method returns a `List<String>`.
My question is: how do I get to loop over the elements of this list of Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an observable you have to subscribe to it to get the actual value. Within subscribtion its up to you, here you can map or loop over your values.

```
this.knowledgeMan.getUserAllowedCases(Item.ItemNumber).subscribe(allowedCases => {
  allowedCases.map(allowedCase => {
    // your code here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this `List<String>` observable to show on the HTML part you can use a combination of `async` and `*ngFor` to get the desired result.

```
//in your html for example
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of (data$ | async)"> {{ item }} </li>
</ul>

//in your component

//usual angular stuff
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<String[]>;
  constructor(private knowledgeMan: YourServiceInterface){}

  ngOnInit() {
    data$ = this.knowledgeMan.getUserAllowedCases(Item.ItemNumber);
  }
}
```

If you are just doing this to compute some value you can do this following.

```
this.knowledgeMan.getUserAllowedCases(Item.ItemNumber).pipe(
  flatMap(),
  map(item => //do something with item here)
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

If as you say, `getUserAllowedCases` returns `string[]` then you can do this:

```
this.knowledgeMan.getUserAllowedCases(Item.ItemNumber).subscribe(x => {
  // assuming x is string[]
  for (const item of x) {
     // use item
  }
});
```